# ORACLE Application Express - how to connect to your tables in production

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've been trying for days but cannot find the answer to this. I am using Oracle Application Express (APEX), someone else setup the initial connection to a "Apex" database in oracle, but I am trying to connect to our production database in oracle. I am making web forms and the web forms are connected to the "Apex" database that was setup already, but I need to connect to our production database so we can create reports from the data entered through the web forms. I need the tables to show up in the create page option from the production database, currently its coming from the apex database, please help.

Create Page View with Tables (from apex)

[image]

Thank You so much in Advance!

Comment: apex runs IN the database, it's the same thing

Comment: Usually there are two workspaces, one to development and other to production. So to do something in production, you need to login in this workspace. If you need to do some dml instruction in a object that have other owner, so you need to made a grant to this object.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "production database"? Is it really a different database (than the one you're currently connected to), or is it a user in the same database?

- if former:

  - you could create a database link between those two databases and create synonyms for production users' tables in one of schemas your workspace is assigned to.
  - another option is to install Apex onto the production database, so that you could use current installation as "development" and then deploy the application into the "production-based" Apex
- if latter, you might do the same (i.e. create synonyms, just without the database link), or simply assign the production schema to your workspace

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to read Mike's response to a question with a similar misunderstanding regarding architecture.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4135843

Once you have your head wrapped around this, you can consider the parsing schema to your application. This schema defines the table access your application has, in the normal way Oracle handles table privileges.

Then it's up to you to define who has access to what pages, using APEX Authorisation Schemes.